# I was asked the following pseudocode in a SQL interview based on joining condition. Can anyone explain what went went wrong with my approach?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

[two tables-ta and tb with respective columns  ][image: 1]

I was asked to put a LEFT JOIN on item id and explain what would be the possible output. I wrote a pseudocode like this-

```
SELECT
    table a.ITEM ID,
    table a.ITEM NAME,
    table b.ITEM ID,
    table b.ITEM NAME
from
    table a
    LEFT JOIN table b ON table a.ITEM ID = table b.ITEM ID;
```

I told them the output would look like this, which they told is not the right answer.

```
ITEM ID ITEM NAME   ITEM ID ITEM NAME
-1      X            -1     P
-1      Y            -1     Q
-1      Z            -1     R
-1      W
```

Can anyone explain what would be the correct answer along with logic?

Comment: Why did you expect that?--Otherwise you're just asking us to rewrite documention/introductions you can find anywhere--including SO. [ask] [help] [mre] PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Couldn't  you create the tables yourself and test to see what output yours produces? It would take less than 5 minutes to do so, and you'd probably learn a few things in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the data in the screenshot was the data they gave you , all item ids are -1
which means no matter if you do inner join or outer join , its gonna be a cross join meaning you will have all combination of table1 with table 2 which will be 12 rows

Comment: Thanks @eshirvana. It gives  the solution. I wanted to know, how despite applying a LEFT JOIN we are getting answer as a CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @SARVESHJOSHI becasue this join condition `a.ITEM ID = table b.ITEM ID` is always true on all the posiible coombinations on two tables

Answer (score 0):

The result is the whole cross product of both tables:

```
 item_id  item_name  item_id  item_name 
 -------- ---------- -------- --------- 
 -1       X          -1       P         
 -1       X          -1       Q         
 -1       X          -1       R         
 -1       Y          -1       P         
 -1       Y          -1       Q         
 -1       Y          -1       R         
 -1       Z          -1       P         
 -1       Z          -1       Q         
 -1       Z          -1       R         
 -1       W          -1       P         
 -1       W          -1       Q         
 -1       W          -1       R
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oiZ4NXLouwqAMDCPmR8XDd/0).

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried this is mock table. This is exactly what I am getting.